# ¿Cómo puedo simular pérdidas de paquetes UDP (multicast) por stress de la CPU?

Tags: ubuntu, redes, wireshark

tengo un pequeño problema. Estoy intentando simular que mi pc tenga pérdidas de paquetes de un tráfico multicast por estrés de la CPU. En concreto, tengo que poder ver desde Wireshark el tráfico multicast con las pérdidas ocasionadas. He intentado utilizar `ìptables` pero Wireshark analiza todos los paquetes antes de que pase por el firewall de iptables, y con `tc` no he conseguido resultados. Estoy haciendo las pruebas desde Ubuntu 18.08.

Gracias y un saludo.